# What might be a suitable weatherproof camera for long exposure timelapse photography?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, long-exposure, timelapse

I'm looking for a camera that meets the following criteria:

- Weather proof
- Controllable from PC (If possible from Linux with gphoto, www.gphoto.org)
- At least 15 seconds shutter speed possibility for long exposures
- Cheap, below 150 $ would be perfect (older/used models with less Megapixels are OK)
- Final image does not need to be larger than 1280x720 and should get close to these examples: http://pcdn.500px.net/13982353/f43889759a0765ff74d7ce380e05f7cd85e64cd8/4.jpg or http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3054/2703361367_2fa55fddef.jpg

Can someone give me suggestions for a model?

There is a list of remotely controllable cameras here: http://www.gphoto.org/doc/remote/
It would be of great help if someone could spot a weather proof camera on that list.

I need this for a project. I would like to record one long exposure photo each minute during the night and create a browsable timelapse like gallery of these photos on the web.

Comment: You've failed to provide any clear budgetary requirements, which makes it difficult for anyone to really offer any helpful suggestions. From the list of remote controllable cameras you linked, there is a fairly broad range of prices, so narrowing that range would help a lot. Additionally, it would help to know what kind of IQ you expect from these night shots...larger sensors are going to perform better, with less noise...but will also increase price.

Comment: I've updated the question with more concrete budgetary and quality requirements.

Comment: Get a used GoPro...

Comment: I have trouble finding any info about GoPro shutter speed. So I'm not sure if it can do long exposures...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be a Canon camera, with the [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) firmware. For waterproof Canons, these are the Powershot D10 and D20, both are listed as compatible with CHDK. Waterproof housings are available for other Powershot models, though most are rather expensive.

The CHDK firmware adds options for long exposures, and remote control. For remote control from a PC, you can use a USB cable and the [PTP extension](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/PTP_Extension).

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to opt for a dslr with a waterproof housing to meet your requirements. Generally most cheaper waterproof cameras will allow up to 60 second exposures but no option to tether to a pc.
With most modern dslr's you can tether to a computer and use systems like the [MX2](http://dynamicperception.com) to control movement etc.

Comment: Really? Housings are extremely expensive. A weather-proof camera will do in most circumstances for much less.

Comment: yes but if you read the question, he is looking for a camera that can be tethered to a computer. i don't think cheap waterproof cameras can do that can they?

Comment: Never said cheap. Weatherproof DSLRs are not cheap for some people but much cheaper than a housing.

Comment: I think the term "weather proof" is the culprit here. There is no such thing as weather "proof". There is such a thing as weather resistant, but actually proving that something is completely weather proof is nearly impossible, and unlikely unless the thing is also water proof or otherwise completely sealed. I can understand the misunderstanding, and the recommendation for a waterproof housing, in that context.